# Python time.localtime() function isn't returning the correct date/time (Circuit Python MatrixPortal)

Tags: python, time, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm attempting to create a program for a Circuit Python MatrixPortal M4 board and I'm using the time function just to print timestamps to the serial monitor to assist with debugging. I copied over code that I've used previously for this purpose also for a Circuit Python program and it worked fine on that program. However, on this one it keeps returning the date as January 1st, 2000 and the time starts at 12:30am and will increment from there. I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

This is the code I've used (after importing the time module earlier on)

```
print("Time: ", time.localtime()[3], ":", f'{time.localtime()[4]:02}')
print(time.localtime()[0], time.localtime()[1], time.localtime()[2])
```

and this is what it outputs:

```
Time:  0 : 30
2000 1 1
```

I was expecting it to output this:

```
Time: 11 : 39
2023 3 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Update:
I figured out what was wrong. I didn't realize I needed to sync the board's clock with the internet using `matrix.network.get_local_time()`. That fixed the issue!